# Birt Viewer DataException(Birt-Viewer is not able to show chart, org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException is coming with Birt 4.4.2 and jetty)

Tags: jetty, runtime-error, birt

I'm trying to exceute a birt report (having crosstab and graph of hourly network node statistics), using birt 4.4.2 runtime and jetty. But it is giving the following error. With birt 4.2.2 runtime the same report was running fine.

But after replacing all the 4.2.2 jars with 4.4.2 jars in eclipse and also deploying //lib/birt-runtime-4_4_2/WebViewerExample/WEB-INF/lib, the report is not working. Below is the stacktrace of the error and full stacktrace is attached. Please let me know if anything else is required.

```html
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: A report document error occurred when getting the save stream.
The archive file has been closed.
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.DataEngineContext.openOutputStream(DataEngineContext.java:371)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.DataEngineContext.getOutputStream(DataEngineContext.java:355)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineSession$ReportDocumentShutdownListener.saveNamingRelation(DataEngineSession.java:515)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineSession$ReportDocumentShutdownListener.dataEngineShutdown(DataEngineSession.java:495)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl.shutdown(DataEngineImpl.java:577)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.shutdown(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:521)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.shutdown(AbstractDataEngine.java:358)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.shutdown(DataGenerationEngine.java:154)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.close(ExecutionContext.java:491)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.close(EngineTask.java:1717)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.close(RunTask.java:333)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1346)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:118)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:103)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1352)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1323)
at com.ericsson.ps.util.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1323)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:476)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:589)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:241)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:664)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The archive file has been closed.
at org.eclipse.birt.core.archive.compound.ArchiveFile.createEntry(ArchiveFile.java:421)
at org.eclipse.birt.core.archive.compound.ArchiveWriter.openRandomAccessStream(ArchiveWriter.java:68)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.DataEngineContext.openOutputStream(DataEngineContext.java:362)
... 71 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but we had similar problem a week ago and today again. Solved it with: we uninstalled BIRT from server and installed it back on (the very same export apart from our report template was one tiny bit updated). Reports were running fine afterwards.
I guess next week we'll just reinstall BIRT again...
BR, M